# Python, Calling a program to open a file and run a javascript, PC vs MAC

Tags: javascript, python, macos, adobe

I'm new to programming but am pretty keen on learning python and I'm starting to get the hang of it, I've recently come across an issue that i cant seem to fix. i am trying to locate an adobe illustrator file, open it in illustrator then run an illustrator JavaScript on the file. so far on a PC i have the following which works fine

```
import os
import subprocess
import glob

illustrator = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CC\Support Files\Contents\Windows\Illustrator.exe'
myjavascript = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Adobe Illustrator CC\\Scripting\\Sample Scripts\\JavaScript\\myjavascript.jsx'

for a in glob.glob("%s" %illustrator_file_location):
    print (a)
    subprocess.check_call([illustrator, a])
    print ("file open")
    subprocess.check_call([illustrator, myjavascript])
    print ("script Complete")
```

this script does exactly what i want so long as illustrator is running before i run the script, if illustrator isn't running it doesn't tell python the file is open and the script will stall at:

```
subprocess.check_call([illustrator, a])
```

but this isn't really a problem

The problem is when i come to run this script on a MAC (it needs to be run on a mac as illustrator runs much better) whenever illustrator is called in python a new instance of illustrator opens even if it is already running

the MAC script is as follows

```
import os
import subprocess
import glob

illustrator = '/Applications/Adobe Illustrator CC/Adobe Illustrator.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Illustrator'
myjavascript = '/Applications/Adobe Illustrator CC/Scripting/Sample Scripts/Javascript/myjavascript.jsx'

for a in glob.glob("%s" %illustrator_file_location):
    print (a)
    subprocess.check_call([illustrator, a])
    print ("file open")
    subprocess.check_call([illustrator, myjavascript])
    print ("script Complete")
```

i don't know if the problem is how i am launching illustrator from the application bundle on the mac, it opens ok, and will open the file but when it is called to run the JavaScript another instance of illustrator opens and runs the script rather than it running in the instance already open

also on the MAC illustrator will not tell python the file is open so again the script stalls on

```
subprocess.check_call([illustrator, a])
```

so far i have got around this by using

```
subprocess.Popen([illustrator, a])
time.sleep(30)
```

(its a slow MAC)

Any help will be greatly appreciated